# How to add UDID on the Apple Developer Page?

Tags: ios, iphone, udid, xcode8, diawi

I have archived my project, created an ipa file and uploaded that on the Diawi site. I tried installing in the device (iPHONE 5) but it says that "Unable to complete the download now" with two options "Done" and "Retry".

I got other device's UDID and I need to add it to Apple Developer account and to Diawi but I am not able to do. 
The updates in the Apple Developer Page is not showing the certificates, identifiers options.

Can someone please share the step by step guide of creating an ipa file to sending the diawi link to another person. Please.
I might be doing something wrong from the start itself.

Thank you

Comment: You should have admin access to add new device

Comment: Unless you have added desired device's UDID in developer portal and associate it with your development/distribution profile, you won't be able to get it installed on them. 'Certificates, IDs & Profiles' is the tab(on the left side) in developer site where you will be able to add new device UDIDs. Please try and let me know the issues still facing.

Answer (score 7):

**Step 1:** Go to apple developer site in **"Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles"** -->**Devices**.Select device type and click on + icon.And add the device UDID and name.

**Step 2:** Now create provisioning profile distribution certificate and select the **Ad Hoc** option -->Select **App ID**-->Select devices you want to share the app with -->and download it.Double click on downloaded provisioning

**Step 3:** Now archive and either upload to iTunes for TestFlight or create Build URL using Diawi.
Enjoy!!